# How to link react with redux to add and remove selected movies to the array by clicking on the heart to display them on the favoгites page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

How to link react with redux to add and remove selected movies to the array by clicking on the heart to display them on the favoгites page

Bellow my redux:

action:

```
export function addMovie(id) {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_MOVIE',
        payload: id
    }
}

export function removeMovie(id) {
    return {
        type: 'REMOVE_MOVIE',
        payload: id
    }
}
```

reducer:

```
function favouriteReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_MOVIE':
            return {
                items: state.items.concat(action.payload)
            }
        case 'REMOVE_MOVIE':
        return {
                items: state.items.filter(item => item !== action.payload)
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default favouriteReducer;
```

store:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import favouriteReducer from "./reducers/favouriteReducer";

const redusers = combineReducers({
    favourite: favouriteReducer,
});

const store = createStore(redusers, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

export default store;
```

and my component, where i need to click to add or remove chosen movie

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import './index.css';
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addMovie } from "../../../../redux/actions/favouriteMovie";
import store from "../../../../redux";

const MoviesContext = React.createContext();
const { Provider } = MoviesContext;

const Movie = (props, {addMovie, movies}) => {

  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)

  let onClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('hello');
    setActive(!active);
    addMovie(movies);
  }
  
  return (
    <Provider store={{movies, addMovie}}>
    <Link to= {"/modal/:"+`${props.id}`} id={props.id} className={'movie'}>
        <img src={"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/"+props.poster_path} alt={props.title} className={'main'}/>
        <h1 className={'title'}>{props.title}</h1>
        <div>
            <svg className={active ? 'activeimg' : 'heart'}  onClick={onClick} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 4.248c-3.148-5.402-12-3.825-12 2.944 0 4.661 5.571 9.427 12 15.808 6.43-6.381 12-11.147 12-15.808 0-6.792-8.875-8.306-12-2.944z"/></svg>
        <p className={'text'}>{props.release_date}</p>
        </div>
    </Link>
    </Provider>
  );

};

export {
  MoviesContext
};

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
      movies: state.movie.movies
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addMovie: addMovie,
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Movie);
```

I don't understand how to do it in component.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your "mapDispatchToProps" to have a dispatch as params
but why this mixt between context and redux ?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addMovie } from '../../../../redux/actions/favouriteMovie';
import store from '../../../../redux';

const MoviesContext = React.createContext();
const { Provider } = MoviesContext;

const Movie = (props, { addMovie, movies }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  const onClick = (id) => {
    console.log('hello');
    setActive(!active);
    props.addMovie(id);
  };

  return (
    <Provider store={{ movies, addMovie }}>
      <Link to={'/modal/:' + `${props.id}`} id={props.id} className={'movie'}>
        <img src={'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/' + props.poster_path} alt={props.title} className={'main'} />
        <h1 className={'title'}>{props.title}</h1>
        <div>
          <svg className={active ? 'activeimg' : 'heart'} onClick={() => onClick(props.id)} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M12 4.248c-3.148-5.402-12-3.825-12 2.944 0 4.661 5.571 9.427 12 15.808 6.43-6.381 12-11.147 12-15.808 0-6.792-8.875-8.306-12-2.944z" />
          </svg>
          <p className={'text'}>{props.release_date}</p>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export { MoviesContext };

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    movies: state.movie.movies,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addMovie: addMovie,
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addMovie: (id) => dispatch(addMovie(id)),
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Movie);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but now he writes: Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect (Movie)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect (Movie) in connect options.

Comment: if you don't use the context i suggest to remove this line <Provider store={{ movies, addMovie }}>